# Sizing block-level elements automatically with its content

Tags: html, css

i have the following code (simplified from my source):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="body">
        <div class="mainstuff">...</div>
        <div class="secondarystuff">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when the browser renders the page, it interprets `.body` as having `0` height, and as such, the footer is placed right on top of `.mainstuff` and `.secondarystuff`. Its like `.mainstuff` and `.secondarystuff` are overflowing the .body.

How do you set a property for body so it adjusts its size depending on the content?
It works if the content is not inside an element, but it doesnt seem to adjust its height according to the children divs...

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please provide more code.

Most likely your interior DIVs are either floated or absolute. If they are floated, adding `overflow:hidden` to the parent div should adjust the size to fit the interior divs.

From what you described though it seems that `mainstuff` and `secondarystuff` are `position:absolute` and probably don't have to be. If they are, you should add `position:relative` to your body class div

Answer (score 0):

If you're floating elements, then `.body` (and all other elements which have children which float) should have this CSS property to properly account for their heights:

```
overflow: auto;
```

By looking at that code, you seem to be trying to make a sticky footer. I use this CSS and HTML for mine, as it works quite well with minimal modification: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Answer (score 0):

While setting the overflow does work in most cases, you should not use it as it will cause problems as CSS3 becomes more prevalent. You will experience display issues with text-shadow and box-shadow at a minimum. If you need to clear floats, you should use the latest clearfix method.

http://fordinteractive.com/2009/12/goodbye-overflow-clearing-hack/

http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/12/06/new-clearfix-hack/